# Replace group 1 of a regex with variable in python

Tags: python, regex

```
text = "abcde"
var = "X"
text = re.sub("b(c)d", var, text)
```

Actual output: aXe
Wanted output: abXde

It's replacing the whole pattern, I only want it to replace group 1 of the pattern. How do I make regex do this?

Comment: text = re.sub("(c)", var, text) Try this

Comment: Probable duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42104540/42346

Comment: @MayankSoni Obviously that would work, but the point is I need the surrounding text for reference, but I don't want to include it in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do the job:

```
^([a])([b])([^\n]+)([a])([b])$
```

for verification you can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) website.